# Minimize Google Chrome instead of closing window when X button is clicked

Tags: google-chrome

I want to let Chrome always stay in memory and not closed.

Is there a extension / trick / hack to change the X (close) Button function in Google Chrome from closing window to minimizing window to taskbar ?

Comment: Your best best would be to look around the docs for the chrome extensions to see what they can do, but a quick glance suggests that it's not possible http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html

Comment: I would like to do this for certain Windows, e.g. web.whatsapp.com.